# Beginner - How can I illustrate that an operation should yield null if negative.

Tags: logic

The problem I'm having that may or may not have a solution is trying to find a way of ensuring that if $x < 0$ then $x := 0$.

Just like you could ensure that if $x < 0$ then $x := -x$ with $\sqrt[2]{x^2}$ or $|x|$

Thanks for the help guys, really appreciate it.

Comment: If you explain what the formula is about, your chance for getting an answer is higher.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I'm not sure it's relevant here (actually worried if would be more confusing than anything). I've changed the question around to make things clearer.

Comment: Same question but I did completely rewrite it to keep things as simple and clear as possible.

Comment: Multiply by the indicator function $1[x > 0]$?

Comment: Thanks I'll look into that. I've been playing around and wondering.. Would $\frac{x+|x|}{2}$ work?

Comment: Yeah, that'll do. It's hard to recognise, though - a mathematician would more readily understand multiplying by the indicator function.

Comment: Ok great thanks. And what are the differences in notation? I'm kind of unclear. Is $1_{[x > 0]}$  equivalent to defining cases for $1_A(x)$ and then writing $1_{[0,+\infty)}(x)$ ?

Comment: The notation $x^+:=\max\{x,0\}$ and $x^-:=\max\{-x,0\}$ is quite common. One then has $x=x^+ -x^-$ and $|x|=x^+ + x^-$.

Comment: great thanks I'll add that to the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @patrick-stevens for his help.

If you want to convey that $x := 0$ if $x < 0$ then you can either use the indicator function :
$$ x \mathbb{1}_{x \geq 0}$$

> An indicator function or a characteristic function is a function defined
>   on a set X that indicates membership of an element in a subset A of X,
>   having the value 1 for all elements of A and the value 0 for all
>   elements of X not in A. - Wiki

Or as per @christian-blatter's comment the following notation:
$$x^+$$

> The notation $x^+:= max \{x,0\}$ and $x^−:=max \{−x,0\}$ is quite common.
>   One then has $x=x^+−x^−$ and $|x|=x^++x^−$.

Or if you need to programmatically calculate $x$ you can use:
$$x :=\frac{x+|x|}{2}$$